# Loading the page with gallery takes too long

Tags: php, jquery, html, gallery, loading

I have a list of images and a simple gallery:

```
<ul id="ulBack">
   <li><img src="gallery/01.jpg"/></li>
   <li><img src="gallery/02.jpg"/></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

and then click on `prev` and `next` button:

```
function change(){
var goImg = "url(" + $('#ulBack img' + ':eq(' + n +')').attr('src') + ")";
$('#divGaLL').css('background-image', goImg);
};
```

Works ok if I have 20-30 images, but with 90+ images (7 MB) loading the page takes too long, and firefox v.21 says: connection was reset.

Is there a way to load firstly 10-20 images, and then the rest (during gallery browsing).
Or any other solution.

**Note**: the unordered list #ulBack is not made visible on the webpage.

Comment: Is the #ulBack list visible ?

Comment: @Andri, no, list is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery already, try [this plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). It will not load the images before they are visible in the browser. All you have to do is run this code:

```
$("#ulBack img").lazyload();
```

The website has many examples and tips/suggestions, for example they suggest you to add class `lazy` to all images that you want to load later.

HTML

```
<ul id="ulBack">
   <li><img data-src="gallery/01.jpg" style="display:none"/></li>
   <li><img data-src="gallery/02.jpg" style="display:none"/></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#ulBack {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$("#ulBack img").show().lazyload();
```

Comment: Broxzier, images are not visible at all. Just one by one image is placed as background of a div by clicking a button. Maybe this plugin will not help

Comment: @SunSky They're still `img` elements and have a `src` attribute, so I guess it will work. If not, perhaps you can write something to load the next image once the button is pressed.

Comment: @SunSky Check this out: "[Load Invisible Images](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)".

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want the images only for the gallery navigation, do not set the `src` of the img elements. By setting the `src` elements the browser will send HTTP requests to your server for the images, which can be costly for a large number of images.

What you can do:

HTML:

```
<ul id="ulBack">
   <li><img data-src="gallery/01.jpg" style="display:none"/></li>
   <li><img data-src="gallery/02.jpg" style="display:none"/></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function change(){
var goImg = "url(" + $('#ulBack img' + ':eq(' + n +')').attr('data-src') + ")";
$('#divGaLL').css('background-image', goImg);
};
```